# how to embed single backslash in string in c#

Tags: c#

how do I print a single backslash

I want to print c:\test\

if I use

```
      string IN = "C:\test\\";
```

it's coming out as

```
      "C:\test\\"
```

and if I use

```
      string IN = @"C:\test\";
```

it's coming out as

```
      "C:\\test\\"
```

what's going on ?

Comment: Do you see this using Watch window? Or by Console.Writeline(IN);? Watch window may show the contents of a string using C# syntax, and not the "real" contents as it is printed to console.

Comment: What do you mean by "coming out"? Some debugging tools or IDEs may display the escaped version.

Comment: It's witchcraft that is laddy. Run.. run while you can.

Answer (score 8):

I assume by "coming out" you mean how it looks in the debugger or some other visualization.  The debugger shows all control characters, so it uses `\\` to indicate one slash.  Otherwise you wouldn't know if `\t` meant a slash followed by a `t` or a `Tab` character.

Either of these should give you the appropriate string:

```
string IN = @"C:\test\";
```

or

```
string IN = "C:\\test\\";
```

Answer (score 2):

Where are you printing to? It will always show `\\` in the debug and watch windows but if you do a `Console.WriteLine("\\")` you will get only a single backslash.

You could also try clicking the small magnifying glass icon next to watched values and on debug tooltips. This will show you the string as it will appear when printed - ie. without all the escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You are perfectly ok here. Nothing to worry. The backslashes are escaped, that's why they are doubled.

If you out put this

```
string IN = "C:\\test\";
Console.WriteLine(IN);
```

output wil be

```
C:\test\
```