# .NET String Literal File Path Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a filepath string defined like so:

```
string projectPath = @"G:\filepath\example\example\";
```

however when I debug:

```
projectPath = G:\\filepath\\example\\example\\
```

am I missing something? I thought the @ was for literal string's so I don't have to escape backslashes. If I try escaping

```
string projectPath = "G:\\filepath\\example\\example\\";
```

I get the same problem, any ideas?

**EDIT:** Apparently this is a non-issue, my code just happens to break where projectPath is used:

```
string [] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(projectPath);
```

I guess I have an incorrect path?

**EDIT 2:** the issue wasn't the string, it was an access denied on the folder I tried to access. Oops!

Comment: Can you tell us the text in the error?  It could be an incorrect path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to embed single backslash in string in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18083540/how-to-embed-single-backslash-in-string-in-c-sharp)

Comment: For future questions try to see if question is really scoped to what you trying  to do - there is nothing special about file path - you could have asked more generic question about just strings... (but I see that it would be immediate duplicate instead of surviving for some time).

Comment: @B.K. I guess it must be an incorrect path.

Answer (score 3):

No, the debugger shows the extra backslashes but they are not actually there.So you don't need to be worry.

Comment: Oh, I see. The issue is my function breaks at the line where projectPath is used, so I assumed that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edits and comments, I gather that you might benefit from using `try{}catch(){}` statements in your code.  If it's an invalid `IO` operation, such an invalid path, you would be able to see it from the exception's message and avoid "crashes."

Example:

```
string projectPath = @"G:\filepath\example\example\";
string[] folders = null;

try
{
    folders = Directory.GetDirectories(projectPath);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

You may also try `Directory.Exists()` method:

```
string projectPath = @"G:\filepath\example\example\";
string[] folders = null;

if (Directory.Exists(projectPath))
{
    folders = Directory.GetDirectories(projectPath);
}
```

Although, I prefer `try{}catch(){}`, just in case there's a permissions issue.